# Trying to extract IP from XML using XML nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

From the below xml,i am trying to extract IP,but this doesnt work..I am not sure where i am making a mistake

```
declare @xml xml

set @xml='<auditElement>
  <RequestOrigination>
    <IP>20.20.20.20</IP>
     </RequestOrigination>
</auditElement>'
```

My attempt

```
select 
 b.value('@IP[1]','nvarchar(100)')
 from  @xml.nodes('/auditElement/RequestOrigination') as org(b)
```

**Output needed:**

```
IP
20.20.20.20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `.nodes()`...

And no need for the `@` before `IP`. This would try to read an *attribute* called "IP", but you are reading the content (the `text()`-node) of an *element. Your code would work for something like this:

```
<SomeElement IP="20.20.20.20">
```

You can use `.value()` with the full `XPath` like here:

```
declare @xml xml

set @xml='<auditElement>
  <RequestOrigination>
    <IP>20.20.20.20</IP>
     </RequestOrigination>
</auditElement>';

SELECT @xml.value('(/auditElement/RequestOrigination/IP/text())[1]','varchar(20)');
```

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there! 2 tiny mistakes ..

```
 declare @xml xml

set @xml='<auditElement>
  <RequestOrigination>
    <IP>20.20.20.20</IP>
     </RequestOrigination>
</auditElement>'

SELECT @xml

select 
 b.value('IP[1]','nvarchar(100)')
 from  @xml.nodes('//auditElement/RequestOrigination') as org(b)
```

Comment: You were correct, that the `@` was wrong, the first *tiny mistake*. But the double slash at the beginning of your `Xpath` is not a good idea. This triggers a *deep search*. It will look for an element `<auditElement>` **anywhere** within the XML. In this very simple case it will make no difference, but with a bigger structure this might return wrong results and it will get very slow...